# How can I pay tolls on Japanese expressways?

Tags: japan, driving, tolls, payment

I'm renting a car soon in Japan and am planning to travel on the expressways. What's the best way to pay tolls?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two options.

The easy way is **cash**, which is (at time of writing) still accepted by every toll plaza on every Japanese expressway: just collect a chit on entry and pay when you leave.

But if you're driving longer distances or on multiple days, you'll want to look into getting set up for **ETC** (electronic toll collection, but called "ETC" even in Japanese). This requires both a **reader** mounted on the dashboard, which is standard equipment in Japanese rental cars, and an **ETC card**, which is used to bill you. Getting your own card is a bit of a hassle if you're not a resident, but fortunately *most* (but not all) rental agencies participate in a scheme that lets you rent one for only around ¥300 for two weeks. It's worth calling ahead to check if one will be available though; if not, you can use [Tocoo's postal rental service](https://www.tocoo.jp/etc/index?lang=en).

Convenience aside, while standard toll fees for ETC are exactly the same as paying in cash, having an ETC card also lets you take advantage of a plethora of discount schemes for weekends, late nights, etc: http://www.japanetccard.com/discounts

Particularly useful are the tourist-only regional Expressway Pass schemes, where you can pay flat fees of as little as ¥500/day to use them. http://www.go-etc.jp/english/expressway/index.html

These are quite a deal if you're driving longer distances, as the regular toll is around ¥25/kilometer, meaning (say) Sapporo-Obihiro, a distance of under 200km, would cost you over ¥5000 otherwise.

Comment: +1 I wish I had've known this before I moved (I drove Kyoto to Tokyo for just over ￥7500 + Fuel Cost).

Comment: I did not know about the tourist ETC... Interesting!  And there are a few roads where you still pay as you enter and no gate on exit. The Tokyo Gaikan is one example.

Comment: In my experience, the vast majority of rental cars are equipped with an ETC reader. They will ask if you plan on using expressways and provide you with a card if you do.